# EF Code First self-referential entity mapping without foreign keys

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I have a class with a standard self-referential parent-child relationship; but I don't have a foreign-key column in the database table, only a unique (natural) key.  I want to map parents and children based on two *varchar(64)* fields, `Number` and `ParentNumber` (neither of which are PKs):

```
public class Centre
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // PK
    public string Number { get; set; } // alternative identifier, required, unique, fixed length (64 chars)
    public string ParentNumber { get; set; } // optional (null if no parent centre, otherwise the Number of that centre)

    public virtual Centre ParentCentre { get; set; } // to be populated if this.ParentNumber is not null)
    public virtual IList<Centre> ChildCentres { get; set; } // to be populated if otherCentre.Number == this.ParentNumber for at least one centre)
}
```

Can I specify a mapping with the Fluent API to make this happen?  I don't know how to specify the two non-PK fields in the relationship.

```
HasOptional(c => c.ParentCentre).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentCentreNumber); // this surely won't work because we haven't specified that c.Number should be part of the mapping

Property(c => c.Id);
Property(c => c.Number).HasMaxLength(64).IsRequired().IsUnicode(false).HasColumnAnnotation( IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Number") { IsUnique = true }) );
Property(c => c.ParentNumber).HasMaxLength(64).IsUnicode(false);
```

**Edit**: I am using EF 6.  It looks like this may be impossible without EF Core.  Is that right?

Comment: use HasAlternateKey to set Number as alternative key. then when expressing the relationship you can use the alternate key, check out this link for details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys

Comment: But not in EF6 - not supported.

Comment: @ed why don't you change your primary key in your model then,in db Id can be still primary key, and have an clustered index on it, but on your model you said that it is required and unique, so why not tell EF that Number is your Key column, it is alternate key in the end, and you can pick any of the alternate keys to become PK.

Comment: @hazimdikenli sadly I am not allowed to change the DB as other code and tables are reliant on this table.  If I could I'd simply add a ParentId field as an FK, which would solve a lot of problems!

Comment: I am not recommending to change db, I think you can change your EF model and decorate your number field as primary key.